# Couldn't fetch record from Avro data created by flume hdfs sink

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, flume

```
flume1.sources = kafka-source-1
flume1.channels = hdfs-channel-1
flume1.sinks = hdfs-sink-1
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.kafka.bootstrap.servers= kafka bootstrap servers
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.kafka.topics = topic
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.batchSize = 1000
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.channels = hdfs-channel-1
flume1.sources.kafka-source-1.kafka.consumer.group.id=group_id

flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.type = memory
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.channel = hdfs-channel-1
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.type = hdfs
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.filePrefix = file_prefix
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .avro
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.inUsePrefix = tmp/
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.path = /user/directory/ingest_date=%y-%m-%d
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollCount=0
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollSize=1000000
flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.capacity = 10000
flume1.channels.hdfs-channel-1.transactionCapacity = 10000
```

i am using flume to consume avro data from Kafka and using HDFS sink i am storing that in HDFS.

i am trying to create a hive table over the avro data in HDFS.

i can do msck repair table and could see partitions added to the hive metastore

so when i do select * from table_name limit 1; it fetches me record

but when i try fetching anything more than that i get

**Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Block size invalid or too large for this implementation: -40**

i have also tried giving the below props

```
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.AvroEventSerializer$Builder
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.deserializer.schemaType = LITERAL
flume1.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.serializer.schemaURL = file:///schemadirectory
```

P.S I use kafka connect to push data to Kafka topic.

Comment: If you already use Kafka Connect, why aren't you using HDFS Connector instead of Flume? In any case, have you tried changing `writeFormat = Text`?

Comment: Flume is going to be our sink for all the cases.. And one main reason is kafka connect sink creates partition with upper case but hives metastore in case insensitive so it converts everything to lowercase during table creation. And I didn't change writeformat since documentation says it will make hive and impala unable to read the files

Comment: By default Kafka Connect writes `partition=x`, which is not uppercase, so I don't understand your point. Also, I think Mysql and Postgres are case sensitive for column names... But my point about the format is that Avro is not Text. If you try to put an AvroSerde on data that's actually just plain text, it'll fail to parse it, probable giving an error similar to the one you have... If you download one of those HDFS file, are you able to read it? Or have you tried using the Avro tools JAR file?

Comment: yes i get uppercase column names from the source which i couldn't change to lowercase on the fly. and yes i tried using Avro tools i can get schema from the avro file but i get the same error when i use tojson

Comment: Alright, well, If you have Avro data sitting in Kafka that's using the Confluent Schema Registry, then I don't think Flume can handle that. The alternatives I've found are Connect (which you can use message transforms to edit fields), Flink, Apache Nifi, Streamsets, Apache Gobblin, or Camus (but that doesn't automatically make Hive tables)

Comment: i am using registry less avro converter plugin on my source side so that kafka connect will not conenct to schema registry. https://github.com/farmdawgnation/registryless-avro-converter
it is totally independent of schema registry server

Comment: Okay, then I think you will want `hdfs.serializer=avro_event`, but that will only work for new records, not data that's already written

Comment: when we use avro event we cannot have custom schema right? it always create table with columns header, body and body contains the avro data with schema.. so is there anyways to parse the data from body? i have tried decoding the body but again it resulted in mapredtask failure.

Comment: In Hive you should be able to do `select body.x from table` to get the x field in the struct. My main point is that Avro files need to contain a certain binary structure internally, and file extensions don't really matter, so Flume must be writing then wrong. However, I personally have more experience with the tools listed above than Flume

Comment: ok.. then in that case i need to move back to kafka connect with having some custom partitioner which will convert all the field names to lowercase always. so do you have any idea on creating custom partitioner?

Comment: There's a `connect-transform` module in Maven Central, and lots of examples on Github, I believe

Comment: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [field replacement], found: null
i get this exception when i use connect transform's ReplaceField option at source side and org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Struct objects supported for [field replacement], found: null
at sink side

Comment: and i am using Registry less avro converter as i said before which serializes data as avro

Comment: That `Struct` type has nothing to do with Avro https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.html

Comment: yes that comes when i gave transformation @sink side. but for source it gives this

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [field replacement], found: null